# Is it necessary to run automation scripts(for e.g. Selenium scripts) on all the browsers?

Tags: testing, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver

**Suppose if I need to do smoke testing of my application with automated scripts. Now is it really necessary to run these scripts on all the browsers (for e.g. Chrome, Firefox, IE) to check the stability ?**

Because currently I only use Firefox for with my selenium-webdriver scripts. So, I was just wondering if its necessary to regularly smoke test on all the browsers ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about testing and as such might better fit to http://sqa.stackexchange.com.

Comment: So does this mean that Stackoverflow is only for Programmers ? because I see many testing related tags in Stackoverflow as well..

Comment: Yes, it could be said so. Software Quality Assurance & Testing site is here for a relatively short time and it's not well known. But all the questions related only to testing should be asked there. And yes, there's quite a lot of questions purely about testing here. Some of them might have been asked before that site was set up and some of them might have been overlooked. But such questions doesn't belong here anymore.

Comment: @user2907700: Yes, there are few questions purely about testing (discussions in a theoretical way), which should be migrated to sqa site. For those `selenium`/`watir` questions, they are considered as programming, so they belong here. Basically if the answer needs to coded, the question belongs here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me, it primarily depends on two factors.

- What is the application and how is it written?

For example, if the website is just old fashioned HTML 4 site, then I wouldn't bother testing all browsers. If the target is not some kind of monster web application but just a simple site, I'd just use headless browser PhantomJS to make sure it's functional. However, if we are talking about complex modern-age web applications, then I'd recommend testing against some real browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE at least).

Also, it really depends on the technology used on the site. If something too up-to-date is used to build up the application, then I'd say have a think about and test against old browsers like IE8.

- What browsers do your customers use?

The most important thing I care about is what browsers my customers use. If most of the users use IE6, then IE6 will be my main testing target. Have a look at user data in site's analytics tool, like Google Analytics, MixPanel, etc., to see what's more important.

For example, whenever I see someone asking about how to run Selenium using Safari on Windows, I'd tell them straight away, Safari for Windows is dead, don't do it because it's just a waste of time (unless most customers use it for some strange reason).

- More thoughts from Arran's comment:

One other thing you need to measure is ROI (Return on investment).

UI tests are normally written by developers and require lots of efforts to maintain. If tests are running against Opera, which none of the customers use, developers may end up wastng time trying to maintain unstable failing tests on something would never happen in real environment.

Using more browsers means higher maintaining costs. Look though all UI bugs of the product, how many of them are browser-specific? For instance, if it's about 25% and all about IE, then I'd say run your tests on Chrome (or Firefox) and IE. But if it's only 5%, I'd say testing one browser is enough and don't worry about others.

Comment: It's an interesting topic (although I suspect it'll get closed here because it's a discussion really), and I was talking about it with some colleagues the other day. What do you get out of testing multiple browsers? What's likely to change between browsers? The thing I most fear is these tests should be quick and easy to run. You should get quick feedback about what's broken. Testing it in multiple browsers *may* cover more areas, but it becomes slower (especially in IE).

Comment: A very good answer but I'll wait for few more answers and aggregate them. Thanks!